# Call variable from another class using java

Tags: java, webdriver

i have a code to test a web application using webdriver, the app contains more than 100 elements.
My testing code works fine but if one day if one of the element is modified i will have to change in all my code everywhere is use this element.
So i want to put all element as String in one class and then call one of the element from another class.

How can do this?
For example:
my test code for gmail inbox:

```
public class ShowInbox {

    public ShowInbox(WebDriver driver) {


        driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl());
        Utility.wait(3);
        String Inbox = "J-Ke n0";
        String MsgSuivis = "J-Ke n0 aBU";

        try {
        driver.findElement(By.className(Inbox)).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Boîte de réception exists");
        driver.findElement(By.className(Inbox)).click();
        } 
catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
System.out.println("Boite de réception is not displayed");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("continue");
        }

        try {

            driver.findElement(By.className(MsgSuivis)).isDisplayed();
            System.out.println("Messages suivis exists");
            driver.findElement(By.className(MsgSuivis)).click();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Messages suivis is not displayed");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("continue");
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

This code is working well when it runs.
Now i want to create a class which will contain only
String Inbox = "J-Ke n0";
String MsgSuivis = "J-Ke n0 aBU";
And then in another i want to call for example only Inbox and then the code to test the inbox.

Any help please, thank you

Comment: Why is this question tagged with WebDriver? It has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are looking for a separate class to store your constant strings. This is done by creating a new class and making the fields public. There are also a few good practices for this:

ElementNames.java

```
public final class ElementNames {

    public static final String Inbox = "J-Ke n0";
    public static final String MsgSuivis = "J-Ke n0 aBU";
    // ... more names

    private ElementNames() { } // Private default constructor
}
```

Here, `public` allows access to the variables from outside the class. `static` allows access to the variables without creating an instance of the class. `final` is important so that the value is constant and cannot be modified after initialization.

Another common pattern is to create a private default constructor so that someone doesn't accidentaly create an instance of the constants class.

To use the new constants:

ShowInbox.java

```
public class ShowInbox {

    public ShowInbox(WebDriver driver) {

        // ...
        driver.findElement(By.className(ElementNames.Inbox)).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Boîte de réception exists");
        driver.findElement(By.className(ElementNames.Inbox)).click();

        // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Exactly, thank you for your help, it looks correct, so now if one element is modified i just have to change it in ElementNames class

Comment: @user3830572 Yes. Also look at my edit.. I added some more explanation and guidelines.

Comment: where can i see your edit? for more explanation and guidelines

Comment: @user3830572 it's just the latest answer body that you see. I added some content in there.